# how to prevent my DNN / MLP converging to average

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, mlp

I want to use available several features to predict a variable. It does not seem to be related to vision or NLP. Although I believe there are good reasons that the variable to be predicted is a non linear function of these features. So I just use normal MLP like following:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(53, 200)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(200, 100)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(100, 36)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(36, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.leaky_relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.leaky_relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.leaky_relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = self.fc4(x)
        return x
net = Net().to(device)
loss_function = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, weight_decay= 1e-6)


def train_normal(model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch):
    model.train ()
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate (train_loader):
        data = data.to (device)
        target = target.to (device)
        optimizer.zero_grad ()
        output = model (data)
        loss = loss_function (output, target)
        loss.backward ()
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 100)
        optimizer.step ()
        if batch_idx % 100 == 0:
            print ('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format (
                epoch, batch_idx * len (data), len (train_loader.dataset),
                       100. * batch_idx / len (train_loader), loss.item ()))
```

At first it seems to work and did learn something:

```
Train Epoch: 9 [268800/276316 (97%)] Loss: 0.217219
Train Epoch: 9 [275200/276316 (100%)] Loss: 0.234965
predicted actual diff
-1.18 -1.11 -0.08
0.15 -0.15 0.31
0.19 0.27 -0.08
-0.49 -0.48 -0.01
-0.05 0.08 -0.14
0.44 0.50 -0.06
-0.17 -0.05 -0.12
1.81 1.92 -0.12
1.55 0.76 0.79
-0.05 -0.30 0.26
```

But when it kept learning, I saw the results seemingly to be close to each other's  average regardless the different input:

```
predicted actual diff
-0.16   -0.06   -0.10
-0.16   -0.55   0.39
-0.13   -0.26   0.14
-0.15   0.50    -0.66
-0.16   0.02    -0.18
-0.16   -0.12   -0.04
-0.16   -0.40   0.24
-0.01   1.20    -1.21
-0.07   0.33    -0.40
-0.09   0.02    -0.10
```

What technology / trick can prevent it? Also, how to increase the accuracy, shall I add more hidden layers or add more neurons of each layer?

Comment: Am I right in assuming all of your features are continuous?

Comment: some are continuous, some are discreet. None is categorical.

Answer (score 0):

- One possible problem is that there is **nothing to learn**.
- Check that your data is standardized and try different **learning rates** (maybe even cyclic learning rate). Something that can be happening is that the algorithm is not able to get inside the minima and keeps jumping around.
- I am not sure, if you are using it but, use a **standard implementatio**n that works in another dataset and then change it to your problem, just to avoid small development mistakes. You can check either this tutorial [How to apply Deep Learning on tabular data with FastAi](https://confusedcoders.com/data-science/deep-learning/how-to-apply-deep-learning-on-tabular-data-with-fastai) but if you are really new I will totally recommend doing this MOOC https://course.fast.ai/. This should allow you to gain some level and understanding.
- If you have all tabular data already you can try to use a **machine learning algorithm** like [linear regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)/gradient boosting. Just to check if your data has some info.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
>>> X = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3]])
>>> # y = 1 * x_0 + 2 * x_1 + 3
>>> y = np.dot(X, np.array([1, 2])) + 3
>>> reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
>>> reg.score(X, y)
1.0
>>> reg.coef_
array([1., 2.])
>>> reg.intercept_
3.0000...
>>> reg.predict(np.array([[3, 5]]))
array([16.])
```

Let me know if you find the solution to your problem!

Comment: I'm new to ML. Can you explain where to find the "standard implementation" and the "linear regression/gradient boosting"?

Comment: I just updated with some links an tutorials that should help you to get started.

Comment: If you want to use some more classical implementation easily, you can also look at sklearn, it provides good implementation for almost all classic machine learning methods. And the documentation is clear and easy to understand